# Session storage error for output element

Tags: javascript, html, input, output, session-storage

Session storage not working for html output element.

I have a html range slider with an associated output element.

I have the session storage working for the range slider but it is not working for the output element as I keep getting null

I have included my snippet on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azggg0k1/) so you can see it working
and here is my snippet

```js
if (true) {

  var weightOut = document.getElementById('weightOutputId'),
      weightIn = document.getElementById('weightInputId');

  weightOut.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightOutputId');
  weightIn.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightInputId');

  weightOut.addEventListener('input', function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightOutputId', weightOut.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightInputId', weightIn.value);
  }, false);
  
}
```

```html
<label for="weightOutputId">
  Weight (kg):
</label>
<output name="weightOutputName" id="weightOutputId">
  1
</output>
<input type="range" name="weightInputName" id="weightInputId" value="1" min="1" max="10" oninput="weightOutputId.value = weightInputId.value">
```

Comment: sessionStorage can only store strings. You need to convert the data to `Number`: `weightOut.value = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('weightOutputId'));`

Comment: just realised my issue,

Comment: snippet corrected, i only needed one event listener